# onlyoffice : How to retrieve document after conversion

Tags: php, onlyoffice

I'm using onlyoffice to convert a file from docx to pdf (Documentation here : https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/conversionapi).

I use curl to execute the example, and it works. I get the file url back, but the only issue is that when I try using this url (in a browser or downloading with file_get_contents), I have a 403 error.

There is nothing in the documentation that speak about the next steps post conversion, so I was wondering if someone could give me a hint. Is there an api method undocumented or something like that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url in the xml back is sent back with html characters in it.

htmlspecialchars_decode on the url resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the file url back, but the only issue is that when I try using
>   this url

Please make sure that you use the link with all parameters. [secure_link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html) should also be included into the download link. If that doesn't help send us the link that you get.

Comment: Yes I use the link with all the arguments. Still get 403. What do you mean by including secure_link in the download link ?